# How to test for index out of bounds error?

Tags: java, string, testing, indexing

I have the following method written that gets a substring from a string with the start and end index. For indexed that will go out of bounds, how do I write a test case in Junit? For example, if the string is banana and the method is run as getSubstring(3,12), the method will throw a out of bounds error. How do I write a test case that will pass when this error is shown?

```
public String getSubstring(int start, int end){
        sub = MyString.str.substring(start, end);
        return sub;
    }



@Test
public void testgetSubstring() {
    MyString test = new MyString();
    String result = test.getSubstring(3,12);
}
```

Comment: Use string length function

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this in JUnit, but the best way is to use the `ExpectedException` feature.  You set up a `@Rule` that specifies that your test might throw an exception, and you can set expectations of what this exception will be - what type it will have, what message and so on.

At the top of your test class, you want something like

```
@Rule public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();
```

and then before the line of code which ought to throw the exception, you can write something like

```
exceptionRule.expect(MyException.class);
```

Then, your test will succeed if the right exception is thrown; but it will fail if it reaches the end without the exception being thrown.

See the [Javadoc](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) for more expectations that you can set up in `ExpectedException` rules.